# How to write into the USB (External storage)

Tags: java, file, usb

I am trying to copy a file from my computer to USB in java. The problem is, the code creates a file on the Usb but the content of the file is not copied from source to destination(computer to usb). How can i do that?
I want the filename R.java to be copied into the usb as system.txt.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class R {

private static File to;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // current working dir where there is file u want to replicate
    File f = new File("." + "/R.java");

    // destination location
    File so = new File("/media");
    for (File s : so.listFiles()) {
        String r = s.getName();
        to = new File("/media/" + r + "/system.txt");
        if (!to.exists()) {
            try {
                to.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out
                        .print(to.getName() + " " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
            }
        }
            if (f.exists()) {
                FileChannel is = null;
                FileChannel os = null;
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(f).getChannel();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    os = new FileOutputStream(to).getChannel();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    os.transferFrom(is, 0, is.size());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

I am on LINUX machine

Comment: I think if you properly indented your code (your IDE has a "format" option), you'd see the problem: the copy is only done if the `to` file already existed, because it's inside the `else` block.

Comment: It is not working even if i remove the else block. I was trying to add else may be i can work but it didn't work

Comment: Your `transferFrom` part is incorrect, then. But please update your question with the most up-to-date source (without the `else`, for example, and with **proper indentation**).

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOH IT IS NOW WORKING THANK U.......

Comment: OK... I'll just add that you could have saved yourself a lot of code if you used [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29).

Comment: Since "/media" mount some other read only drivers like moderm system.txt is not created and therefore am getting "File not found exeption"